# Rails Console cannot find activesupport-4.1.2 even though it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, activesupport

When I run the Rails 4.1.2 server, I get no errors.

However, if I run 'rails c', I get the following error:

```
Could not find activesupport-4.1.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What's strange is that activesupport-4.1.2 is both installed and is specified in Gemfile.lock.  I have tried 'bundle update' as well as deleting Gemfile.lock and running 'bundle install'.  I have also tried specifying that specific version of ActiveSupport in my Rails gemfile, but this has gotten my nowhere.

I'd really like to use the latest Rails, but it seems pretty crummy that I can't use the console.

FIY: I am using Ruby 2.1.2p95 in Linux with RVM.

EDIT: I uninstalled all activesupport gems and reinstalled 4.1.2.  Here's what 'gem list activesupport says':

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (4.1.2)
```

Same problem.

EDIT2: Here is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.2)
      actionpack (= 4.1.2)
      actionview (= 4.1.2)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.2)
      actionview (= 4.1.2)
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.2)
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.2)
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.2)
      activemodel (= 4.1.2)
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    akami (1.2.2)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capybara (2.3.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    database_cleaner (1.3.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.1)
    gyoku (1.1.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httpi (2.1.0)
      rack
      rubyntlm (~> 0.3.2)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (2.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    kgio (2.9.2)
    libv8 (3.16.14.3)
    macaddr (1.7.1)
      systemu (~> 2.6.2)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.0)
    minitest (5.3.5)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.16)
    nokogiri (1.6.2.1)
      mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
    nori (2.4.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.2)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.2)
      actionpack (= 4.1.2)
      actionview (= 4.1.2)
      activemodel (= 4.1.2)
      activerecord (= 4.1.2)
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.2)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.2)
      actionpack (= 4.1.2)
      activesupport (= 4.1.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.13.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    rdoc (4.1.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    rspec-core (3.0.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.0.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.0.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-rails (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
    rspec-support (3.0.2)
    rubyntlm (0.3.4)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    savon (2.5.1)
      akami (~> 1.2.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (~> 1.1.0)
      httpi (~> 2.1.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
      nori (~> 2.4.0)
      uuid (~> 2.3.7)
      wasabi (~> 3.3.0)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    simplecov (0.7.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.7.1)
    simplecov-html (0.7.1)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    subactions (1.0.1)
    systemu (2.6.4)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.2.2)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unicorn (4.8.3)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    unicorn-rails (2.1.1)
      rack
      unicorn
    uuid (2.3.7)
      macaddr (~> 1.0)
    version (1.0.0)
    wasabi (3.3.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0)
      mime-types (< 2.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  database_cleaner
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  mysql2
  rails (= 4.1.2)
  rspec-rails (~> 3.0.0)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  simplecov (~> 0.7.1)
  simplecov-html
  spring
  sqlite3
  subactions
  therubyracer
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn
  unicorn-rails
  version
```

EDIT3: Here is my .irbrc file:

```
# This loads some niceties for irb, courtesy of rvm.
# It also loads your custom ~/.irbrc if it exists.
# If you want to customize the irbrc for ONLY this version of
# ruby then edit this file. It will only be deleted if you do
# an "rvm install" over this ruby version.

if ENV["rvm_path"].nil?
  require File.join(ENV["HOME"], "irbrc")
else
  require File.join(ENV["rvm_path"], "scripts", "irbrc")
end
```

Comment: What if you run: `bundle exec rails c`? or `./script/rails c`?

Comment: Checkout your `Gemfile.lock` file, please post that

Comment: Remove Gemfile.lock and then do bundle install

Comment: `bundle exec rails c` makes no difference.  I already removed Gemfile.lock and bundle installed(please read my question).

I will add my Gemfile.lock to my question.

Comment: Maybe something weird in your .irbrc?

Comment: I have now included my .irbrc file for ruby 2.1.2 in my question.

Comment: To rule out the possibility of `spring` interfering, which I have ran into from time to time.  Run `spring status` to check it's status.  Try stopping it using `spring stop` then `bundle` then `rails c`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spring was still running and interfering.  Running the following in the shell did the trick:

```
spring stop
```

Now Rails console works as it should.

Comment: fixed this exact same issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me from hours of confusion and pain :)